# How to resolve int object is not iterable error when averaging input values for a Python array

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

I'm creating a program that takes user input for pints of blood collected each hour for 7 hours and then outputs the `average`, `maximum`, and `minimum`. I can't overcome the `"int object is not iterable"` error. I'm relatively new to Python and so I'm not quite sure what this error indicates other than there is a sort of in-equivalency in the iterations.

```
inputPints = 0
totalPints = 0
hours = ["#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5", "#6", "#7"]

def averagePints(totalPints, hours):
    return totalPints / hours

def maxPints():
    return max(inputPints)

def minPints():
    return min(inputPints)

def userInput():
    for hour in hours:
        inputPints = int(input("Enter pints collected for hour {}: ".format(hour)))
userInput()

totalPints = totalPints + inputPints

print("")
print("Average number of pints donated is: ", averagePints(totalPints, 7))
print("Most pints donated is: ", maxPints())
print("Least pints donated is: ", minPints())
print("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `int` is a single value you can't iterate over in a loop.
You want to use a list for the `inputPints` and then you append values to the list. Then you can also use `sum` besides `max` and `min`. And you have also `len(inputPints)` at disposal by the way.

```
inputPints = []
totalPints = 0
hours = ["#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5", "#6", "#7"]

def averagePints(totalPints, hours):
    return sum(inputPints) / hours

def maxPints():
    return max(inputPints)

def minPints():
    return min(inputPints)

def userInput():
    for hour in hours:
        inputPints.append(int(input("Enter pints collected for hour {}: ".format(hour))))

userInput()

totalPints = sum(inputPints)

print("")
print("Average number of pints donated is: ", averagePints(totalPints, 7))
print("Most pints donated is: ", maxPints())
print("Least pints donated is: ", minPints())
print("")
```